# Help me name this Arcade game?

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game, arcade

Help me identify an arcade game I played, trying to remember what it was called..

All i remember it was a 2D platformer cartoon-like person character which had a gun and could fly with a jetpack, I remember bosses taking up the whole screen.

It was strictly 2D not 3D. And was a scroller platform game.

It was played in a local arcade (Australia, Melbourne) in the era of '91 or '92

Another memory was it was similar to Willow but with a jetpack....

no car drive scenes, no sky diving or swimming scenes... I remember jetpaking around these large bosses, which took up all of the screen and you had back of in a corner.

Fantasy, with trees, no robots with metal walls

I don't believe it had a port and was arcade only afaik.

Apart from Willow like it resembles Funky Jet quite a bit but it's not that game

It pretty much looked like Willow You had a metal gun And it resembled Tonma arcade game

Games I have investigated but are not correct...

- Act-Fancer
- Alien sector
- Athena
- Avenging Spirit
- Bakutotsu Kijuutei: Baraduke II
- Baraduke
- Battle Chopper
- Bay Route
- Big Karnak
- Biomechanical Toy
- Blue's Journey
- Bomb Kick
- Bonze Adventure
- Bygone
- Cadash
- Charlie Ninja
- Chelnov
- Chiki Chiki Boys
- China Gate
- Cho Zetsurin Jin Beraboman
- Chuka Taisen
- Come Back Toto
- Contra
- Cop 01
- Crime City
- Cyber-Lip
- Demon's world ( toaplan )
- Dragon Breed
- Exzisus
- Fantasy Land
- Finest Hour
- Forgotten worlds (capcom)
- Formation Z
- Funky Jet
- Guardian
- Gun force II
- Gun Master
- GunForce
- Hachoo
- Hammering Harry
- Hard Head 2
- Insector-X
- J. J. Squawkers
- Karnov
- Legend
- LEGEND OF HERO TONMA
- Legend of Kage
- Legend of Makai
- Liquid Kids
- Magic Sword - Heroic Fantasy
- Metal Clash
- Metal slug (released '96)
- Midnight Resistance
- Mystic Riders
- Mystic warriors
- Nemo
- Ninja Baseball Bat Man
- Pistol Daimyo no Bouken
- Pistol Daimyo No Bouken
- Psychic 5
- Psycho Nics Oscar
- Psycho Soldier
- Quartet
- Rabio Lepus
- Rastan
- Recalhorn
- Rohga Armor Force
- Rough Ranger
- SD Gundam Psycho Salamander no Kyoui
- SD Gundam Sangokushi Rainbow Tairiku Senki
- Section Z (capcom)
- Shadow Land
- Sly Spy
- Spark Man
- Spin Master
- Styenx
- Super Contra
- Surprise Attack
- Tatakae! Big Fighter
- The outfoxies
- Three Wonders
- Thunder Fox
- Thunder Hoop
- Top Hunter
- Top Hunter: Roddy & Cathy
- Transformer
- Trojan
- Vastar
- Wardner
- Wild West C.O.W.-Boys of Moo Mesa
- Wolf Fang
- Xain'd Sleena

All replies and added information will no only be added to first post as instructed..

List has been updated to #92 games that are incorrect

Also definitely not any of the 3 games included in Three Wonders

And the game has not been found yet..

Comment: Quartet came to mind first up but you've already checked and discarded. You could try looking at the MAME site or Abandonia (which has lots of pictures but may not help if arcade only).

Comment: Clarification request on "no robots with metal walls". Does this mean "There were no robots. The game had metal walls."? Or does it men there may have been robots but they definitely did not have metal walls?

Comment: Or see if anything at https://www.video-games-museum.com/en/sys/5-mame/1/all rngs a bell.

Comment: Sorry. No robots and no metal walls it was more like fantasy themed with trees.

Comment: It wasn't quartet

Comment: Fantasy themed with trees? And a jetpack? Sounds like the author didn't quite know which genre they wanted :-) Although bookstores often lump SciFi and Fantasy into the same cetegory so maybe understandable (the *good* bookstores do not do this, of course).

Comment: Even if you listed it, maybe take another closer look at "Three Wonders". It's 3 quite different games in one after all, but all very Willow-ish. Have you checked all 3 parts?

Answer (score 2):

Was it [Space Ranger](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=amiga%20space%20ranger#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:1da37ae8,vid:DTKQS4tclcE) maybe? This was a game for the quite rare Amiga Arcadia system, which was a collaboration between Amiga and MasterTronic to create an arcade system with interchangeable games.